# JS items that know about their collection?

Tags: javascript, collections, prototype, items

Sometimes you need that tight coupling between the items  of a collection.

For my example I wish to encapsulate chess board tile refs to avoid direct string manipulation in code.

```
var ref = new Ref("a1");
```

to use them properly as objects :

```
ref.move({ col : 2, row : 1 }); // --> Ref("c2")
```

thus allowing chaining methods :

```
var ref = new Ref("a1")
  .move({ col : 2, row : 1 })
  .move({ col : -2, row : -1 })
// --> Ref("a1"), same object as initial
```

(with Ref.prototype.move defined...)

surely with something like :

```
Ref.BOARD = [ new Ref("a1"), ..., new Ref("h8") ]

Ref.ALL = the same + borders + corners
```

But to do that I need to have knowledge in my objects of the whole collection !

How to implement that properly ?

Comment: Generally it is one-or-the-other. Otherwise you have to maintain the order association manually: this requires updating the collection *and* the item.

Comment: basically, I have decided/defined a constructor for the whole collection (Refs) and the constructor of a single Ref inside the scope of Refs... the closure does the trick...